# Баги в построении выпуклой оболочки

Tags: c++, алгоритм

В алгоритме Грэхема происходит ошибка: нарушение прав доступа. Я прошел отладчиком и сделал кое-какие предположения. Вот код:

```
struct Point{
    int x;
    int y;
};

Point nextToTop(stack<Point> &S){
    Point p = S.top();
    S.pop();
    Point res = S.top();
    S.push(p);
    return res;
}

int swap(Point &p1, Point &p2){
    Point temp = p1;
    p1 = p2;
    p2 = temp;
    return 1; //Успех
}

int orientation(Point p, Point q, Point r){
    int val = (q.y - p.y) * (r.x - q.x) -
              (q.x - p.x) * (r.y - q.y);

    if (val == 0) return 0;  // коллинеарны
    return (val > 0)? 1: 2; // по часовой стрелке или против
}

int compare(const void *vp1, const void *vp2){
    Point *p1 = (Point *)vp1;
    Point *p2 = (Point *)vp2;

    // Находим ориентацию
    int o = orientation(p0, *p1, *p2);
    if (o == 0)
        return (dist(p0, *p2) >= dist(p0, *p1))? -1 : 1;

    return (o == 2)? -1: 1;
}

void GrahamScan(Point points[], int n, std::vector<Point> &result){
    // Находим самую нижнюю точку
    int ymin = points[0].y, min = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        int y = points[i].y;

        // Выбираем самую нижнюю или самую левую из них в случае совпадения
        if ((y < ymin) || (ymin == y && points[i].x < points[min].x))
            ymin = points[i].y, min = i;
    }

    // Помещаем самую левую точку в начало
    swap(points[0], points[min]);

    // Сортируем n-1 точек по отношению к первой точке.  Точка p1 становится
    // перед p2 в отсортированной последовательности, если p2 имеет больший полярный угол (в 
    // направлении по часовой стрелке), чем p1
    p0 = points[0];
    qsort(&points[1], n-1, sizeof(Point), compare);

    // Создаем пустой стек и кладем в него первые три точки.
    stack<Point> S;
    S.push(points[0]);
    S.push(points[1]);
    S.push(points[2]);

    // Обрабатываем оставшиеся n-3 точек
    for (int i = 3; i < n; i++){
        // Продолжаем удалять верхнюю точку, пока угол, сформированный точками next-to-top, 
        // top, and points[i] не образует левый поворот
        while (orientation(nextToTop(S), S.top(), points[i]) != 2)
            S.pop();
        S.push(points[i]);
    }

     // Теперь в стеке нужные точки
    while (!S.empty()){
        Point p = S.top();
        //cout << "(" << p.x << ", " << p.y <<")" << endl;
        result.push_back(p);
        S.pop();
    }
}
```

Алгоритм генерации большого выпуклого многоугольника:

```
void genLargeRectangle(int amount, std::vector<g::Point> &rect, int &generated){
    //Генерируем множество из amount точек
    g::Point *p = new g::Point[amount];
    genRandPointVariety(p, amount);
    //Строим для них выпуклую оболочку по Грэхему
    std::vector<g::Point> convex_hull;
    GrahamScan(p, amount, convex_hull);
    //Количество точек в оболочке (вершин многоугольника)
    generated = convex_hull.size();
    //Копируем точки из вектора в массив rect
    rect.assign(convex_hull.begin(), convex_hull.end());
    delete[] p;
}
```

Функция генерации множества точек:

```
void genRandPointVariety(g::Point points[], int amount){
    std::vector<g::Point> v;
    g::Point *p = NULL;

    //Генерируем множество произвольных точек в количестве amount
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
        int x = std::rand() % 1024;
        int y = std::rand() % 1024;
        p = new g::Point();
        p->x = x;
        p->y = y;
        v.push_back(*p);
        delete p;
    }

    //Удаляем повторяющиеся точки, если такие есть
    std::vector<g::Point>::iterator it;
    it = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(), pt_cmp);
    v.erase(it, v.end());

    //Если после удаления точек в векторе меньше, чем нужно,
    //Добавляем по одной, проверяя уникальность
    while(v.size() < amount){
        int x = std::rand() % 670;
        int y = std::rand() % 670;
        p = new g::Point();
        p->x = x;
        p->y = y;
        v.push_back(*p);
        it = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(), pt_cmp);
        v.erase(it, v.end());
        delete p;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        points[i] = v[i];
}
```

В отладчике программа падает в этом месте в грэхем скане:

```
while (orientation(nextToTop(S), S.top(), points[i]) != 2)
    S.pop();
```

Сначала в стеке 3 точки. Потом две из них удаляются. Видимо, программа доходит до вызова NextToTop, а там ничего нет, и в этот момент происходит краш.

Как можно исправить все это?

Comment: Ну, это ошибка алгоритма: в пустой стек лезть нельзя. Правьте логику программы, чтобы она и не пыталась.

Comment: Добавил проверку S.size() >= 2 в начало условия цикла, чтобы она вычислялась первой. Вроде, работает, только вершин в многоугольнике получается мало - от 9 до 14.

Comment: `unique` удаляет одинаковые элементы _подряд_. То есть в векторе [(1, 3), (2, 2), (1, 3)] он ничего не удалит. Обычно его используют после `sort`.

Comment: Мало точек в выпуклой оболочке для случайно накиданных в квадрат - это нормально. Можно случайно накидать в круг - будет больше.

Comment: Самопальный swap вы зря написали, есть же std::swap